# How do I exterminate the new unwanted spam icon in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

In the last few days, Firefox has started displaying a new icon near the top-right corner, in the shape of a "present" (I think) with a little blue circle in the corner. When hovering the mouse cursor over it, it says "What's New". When left-clicking it, it displays a bunch of completely irrelevant and unwanted "news", which I neither asked for, nor wish to have anything to do with.

When I right-click the icon, the usual "Remove from Toolbar" feature is disabled!

When I try to enter "customize mode" to forcefully remove this icon, it's nowhere to be found in that interface either!

Are they seriously ***forcing*** this garbage on me permanently? I'm going to regularly see that junk until I left-click it so it disappears? Or is there some way to get rid of it? If not, I might just get rid of Firefox as a thank-you to Mozilla for giving me this "Christmas present".

*(The only problem with that last point is that the only other browser, Chrome, is even worse, and thus not an alternative... so I will apparently have to cease using computers entirely at this point.)*

Comment: While the problem you mention in your question is valid, the tone you use doesn't fit to this site. Please clean up your question to prevent its removal.

Comment: This is not needed, “Are they seriously forcing this garbage on me permanently? I'm going to regularly see that junk until I left-click it so it disappears? Or is there some way to get rid of it? If not, I might just get rid of Firefox as a thank-you to Mozilla for giving me this "Christmas present".”

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to `about:config`
2. Search for `browser.messaging-system.whatsNewPanel.enabled`
3. Set it to `false`